# Using document.write() to output markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a inline svg as a variable on my page. I'm doing some modifications to it. How can I echo `viewText` on the page (not the svg image) with modifications. How can I make `viewText` show on the page?

Example:

```
<script>
var viewText = "<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>"

  var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("rect"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) { 
   //do something 
  }

document.write( viewText );//how do I output the modified 'viewText' code on the page?
/*e.g.: 
<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg> */
 </script>
```

Comment: Down-voter: Please leave a comment as to why my question was down voted. That helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
<div id="target"></div>
<script>
    var viewText = '<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>';

    var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("rect"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) { 
        //do something 
    }

    document.getElementById('target').textContent = viewText;
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `var viewText` in `var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("rect"); ` so the modifications are captured in `document.getElementById('target')`?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an id to your SVG element and use outerHTML:

```
<svg width="400" height="100" id="svg1">
   <rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>

<div id="target"></div>

var yourCode = document.getElementById("svg1").outerHTML;
document.getElementById("target").textContent=yourCode;
```

You will get your SVG as a string and you can put it in a div with id="target":

```
'<svg width="400" height="100" id="svg1">
   <rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect>
</svg>'
```

Comment: Thanks. :) I did `document.write( document.getElementById("svg1").outerHTML )` But it outputs the svg image. I need to be able to see the string with modifications.

Comment: put it in a `<pre>` tag

Comment: yes, although personally I don't think you should ever use `document.write` but there may be valid reasons to do so - I haven't come across one since the new millenium though

Comment: @JaromandaX 
 
I wrapped the svg in a pre tag, added the id to the pre tag. But still I see the image instead of the modified string.

Comment: What do you recommend instead of `document.write`?

Comment: yeah .. <pre> doesn't seem to do what I thought it would ... If you had an element, say a `<div id="target"></div>` then you could simply put `document.getElementById('target').textContent = yoursvgstring;` and it'd be sweet