# Outputting modified textContent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a svg as a string and I'm doing some modifications to it. I'm outputting the svg as text into `targetDiv`.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Output Modified</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="targetDiv"></div>
    <script>
        var viewText = '<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>';

        var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("rect"); 
        for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) { 
            //do modifications to rect (e.g. height="200") 
        }

        document.getElementById('targetDiv').textContent = viewText;
    </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

At the moment the output is same as `viewText`. My question is how can I output the modified svg MARKUP?

Comment: Use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. I did `document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerHTML = viewText;` but the page is blank (no text seen on the browser).

Comment: Add your complete code in the question, I guess you've included `script` in `<head>`

Comment: @Tushar: Thanks see my edit. That's the full page.

Comment: DOM methods on the `document` will only search elements that have already been attached to the document tree. They don't also search within strings of markup. Try assigning `innerHTML` before retrieving `var rect`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9rv5x1u3/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you. I do not need the svg image to show. But I need only the modified markup to be shown on the page. So the output will be `<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="200"......`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thank you. I'm looking to output the svg MARKUP instead of the svg image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a temp element to modify the contents

```js
 var viewText = '<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>';
 var tmp = document.createElement('div');
 tmp.innerHTML = viewText;

 var rect = tmp.getElementsByTagName("rect");
 for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
   rect[i].style.height = '200px'
 }

 document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerText = tmp.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. :) But I don't see the markup on the page. It is blank. Am I missing something? I want the page to show the modified svg markup. ( e.g.: `<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="200"......` )

Comment: @Bekki I added a `height` style.. so `stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); height: 200px;"></rect>`

Comment: OOPs!!! sorry. I'm using FF. It works perfectly on chrome. Thank you! :) #up-vote and correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Output Modified</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="targetDiv"></div><script>
        var viewText = '<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /><\/svg>';
            document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerHTML= viewText;
            var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("rect"); 
            for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) { 
                //do modifications to rect (e.g. height="200") 
            }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Set the innerHTML before calling `getElementsByTagName("rect")`

Comment: Thank you. I need to output the modified svg MARKUP instead of the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery (as seen by tag) this would be a lot simpler:

```
<html lang="en">    
    <head>
        <title>Output Modified</title>
        <script>
            var viewText = '<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>';
            $('#targetDiv').html(viewText);

            var rect = $('rect');
            for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
                //do modifications to rect (e.g. height="200") 
            }
        </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div id="targetDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT as per comment:

```
var viewText = '<svg width="400" height="100"><rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>';

var rect = $('rect');
var text="";
for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
    //do modifications to rect (e.g. width="200")
    console.log(text);
    text += 'Set width="200" <br />';
    //do modifications to rect (e.g. height="400")
    text += 'Set height="400"';
}
$('#targetDiv').html(text);
```

have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn0ztLLt/)

Comment: Thank you. :) I need to output the modified svg MARKUP instead of the svg image.

Comment: @Bekki so you want to output what you do in the for loop inside the target div? e.g if you set hight 200 you want the div to give the text hight set to 200?

Answer (score 1):

You have viewText manually typed as a string. If you want to be able to get the html of the svg after you make changes, you could try this:

```
<svg width="400" height="100" id="svg1">
   <rect width="400" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>

<div id="targetDiv"></div>

<script>
    var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("rect"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) { 
        //do modifications to rect (e.g. height="200") 
    }

var viewText = document.getElementById("svg1").outerHTML;
document.getElementById("targetDiv").textContent=viewText;
</script>
```

Comment: By the way, I think other people aren't sure what you're asking for because they didn't see your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366251/using-document-write-to-output-markup). In this question, you didn't include your actual svg code.

Comment: Thanks. What is `yourCode`?

Comment: Should be viewText. Edited.